# How to cast a List<T> object into Text

Tags: c#, list, casting

I want to know if I can access an item of my `List` and assign it to a `textbox`?

```
public static List<Product> detailsList = new List<Product>();
```

`Product` is my class generated by using `LINQ to SQL` with fields `Name,Code,Details` i.e my List contains the `items(Name,Code,Details)`. I want to access the value of the item `Details` from the list and assign it to a `textbox` . Something like:

`txtDetails.Text = detailsList.Details.ToString()`

Comment: This list contains number of items. Which Item list detail do you wanna show

Comment: You want to join the Detail together?

Comment: @User2012384 No, I just want to access one of the items of my List so I can assign it to a textbox

Comment: @HumaAli check RoteS's answer

Comment: How do you want to filter the list to get the single item?  Should it be based on Name or Code?  Do you want the first item, last, or a particular index?  Do you want to skip a certain number of items? Etc.

Comment: Can you show definition of your `Product` class?

Comment: Did actually none of the answers helped you?

Comment: @DovydasSopa I tried Rote S indexing technique. Worked! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the details of 1 item:

```
var detailsList = new List<TaskDto>();
// add items

// this if you know the corect index
txtDetails.Text = detailsList[0].Details;

// if you need to query for example for the item with the correct Id
txtDetails.Text = detailsList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1).Details;
```

Answer (score 0):

For all items:

```
var joinSymbol = ", ";
txtDetails.Text = string.Join(joinSymbol, detailsList.Select(detail => detail.Details));
```

For first item if `Details`:

```
txtDetails.Text = detailsList.FirstOrDefault()?.Details ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select first or default from the item based on some criteria, like the name.

```
public static List<Product> detailsList = new List<Product>();
var prod = detailsList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == 'Ana');

if(prod != null) {
    txtDetails.Text = prod.Details;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `string.Join()` function.

```
txtDetails.Text = string.Join(",", detailsList.Select(e => e.Details)).ToList());
```

Comment: `string.Join` takes parameters in reversed order.

Comment: @DovydasSopa you are right, just edited my post. thanks